# "The package can be picked up till 5 p.m." or "the package can be picked up by 5 p.m."?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Would you tell me if I have to use *till* or *by* in the context below?

> The package can be picked up **till** 5 p.m. and then we close.
>
> The package can be picked up **by** 5 p.m. and then we close.

Generally speaking I'm aware of when to use *till* and *by*, but that context is giving me a hard time. I feel they both might be correct in the context; if so, what is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Also see [discerning between until and by](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48521/discerning-between-until-and-by)

Comment: Thank you for the links, but they don't provide an answer for my context.

Comment: It is clearer to say "by", which basically means _before_. The word "until" signifies the minimum duration of a situation or activity. So if the package can be picked up **until** 5PM you might keep picking it up all afternoon. Common sense might tell you this was unnecessary but using "by" in your sentence would avoid ambiguity. Or you could say, "The package will be available for collection until 5PM."

Comment: In America, the first sentence is preferable. You'd use *by* only in commands: "Pick up your package by 5PM." *Until* is understood as "this is the latest time you can pick it up; after this time, you cannot."

Comment: Generally agree with @FeliniusRex - would add that "by" is appropriate for non-direct commands too - e.g., "the package must be picked up by 5." But I don't think it's too awful, here, with "can be" - just not as idiomatic.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I disagree. The package _can_ be picked up (at any time) until 5.00, but it _must_ be picked up before 5.00.

Comment: `Thank you for the links, but they don't provide an answer for my context.` You need to start explaining your confusion and/or your perplexities. Do some research, put a minimal amount of effort and explain your confusion between "by" and "until". Until then, you're always going to get users either not upvoting or closing your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually "till 5PM" is far better here. If you use "*can be picked up till 5PM*", the "*till 5PM*" modifies "*can be picked up*" and so the whole sentence asserts that "*the package can be picked up*" remains true until 5PM. So there is nothing wrong with the first option. If you use "*can be picked up by 5PM*", the "*by 5PM*" modifies only "*picked up*" and so "*The package can be picked up by 5PM.*" asserts that you can do anything you like as long as you pick up the package by 5PM, which is fine too.

But the second option is a bit odd because of the "*and then we close*". It would be far better to say:

*The package should be picked up by 5PM as we close at that time.*

In contrast, the "*and then we close*" is perfectly fine in the first option because there is a progression of events:

possibly the package is picked up → 5PM → we close.

Answer (score -1):

Answer: BY
The sentence: The parcel can be picked up till 5PM and then we close.
The meaning: The parcel is picked up all the way to 5PM. This is obviously not the intended meaning.
The sentence: The parcel can be picked up by 5PM and then we close.
The meaning: The last time to pick the parcel is 5PM (when we close)